# Spring MVC. Несколько параметров в реквесте

Tags: spring

Сейчас пишу REST API и нужно принять несколько параметров. Вдруг понял, что за полгода забыл как это делать. 
Как мне в `@RequestMapping` описать такой запрос?

`https://secure.host.co.uk/url.aspx?req=evr&em=tony@email.com`

Чтобы я мог принять **req** и **em**?
Можно это сделать просто через **@RequestBody**? Если я правильно помню .. ?

Comment: @RequestParam(value = "req", required = false) String req, @RequestParam(value = "em", required = false) String em

Comment: @carapuz а чтобы не делать через **RequstParam** можно сделать все таки через бади?

Comment: @RequestBody для получения тела запроса, а у Вас  параметры в урле идут

Comment: @carapuz ну я это понял. но оно же походу может спарсить входные данные джейсона как параметра, если я правильно помню. просто нету времени проверять сейчас

Comment: Нет, так не делается. Вот тут есть пояснение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468572/spring-mvc-why-not-able-to-use-requestbody-and-requestparam-together

Comment: @carapuz проблема в том, что этот пример не с рестом

Answer (score 2):

Немного не понятен вопрос. Если Вам нужно принять параметры в контроллер то используйте @RequestParam, если нужно вызвать определенный метод в контроллере то тогда используйте @RequestMapping. Сейчас пишу похожее приложение и вот мой метод в контроллере:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String search(@RequestParam Integer idProvider,
        @RequestParam String department,
        @RequestParam String carNumber,
        @RequestParam ("arrivalDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate startDate,
        @RequestParam("arrivalDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) LocalDate endDate,
        @ModelAttribute("idAttribute") Supply supply, Model model) throws DaoException {

    List<Supply> supplyList = supplyDao.searchByCriteria(idProvider, department, carNumber, startDate, endDate);
    model.addAttribute("supplyList", supplyList);

    return "searchList";
```

Comment: да,  я понимаю как принимать методы и тд. я имел ввиду, что мне в определенном методе нужно принять несколько параметров, на насколько я помню, в рестовом приложении использовать `@RequetsParam` не надо.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/url.aspx")
  public ResponseEntity<YourResponse> get(@RequestParam("req") String req, @RequestParam("em") String em) {
    
  }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы.
[Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию.
Изложите свои предложения.
Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].